# What is ec2-authorize?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, amazon-ec2

I am new to EC2 and am trying to get it set up so that I can publish directly to it from VS2008. Everyone keeps mentioning using "ec2-authorize" to enable certain things, but what the heck is this? Nowhere seems to explain what it is or where it's accessed from. I tried it from a command line in the actual ec2 instance, but there's nothing there.

P.S. I'm using a Windows instance of EC2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are you trying to do exactly? Manage large number of instances or just publish/deploy new code to one instance?

[ec2-authorize](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/2009-03-01/DeveloperGuide/index.html?CLTRG-authorize.html) is a simple command to control firewall rules related to your instance(s), like port 80 for your Web Server.

You don't have to install Java, if it's just a small number of instances/operations you can use [EC2 Console](http://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/home) which does support most of the operation from EC2 API.

Comment: Awesome. I did look through the management console, but apparently missed it. Now that I look closer I do see some security group stuff. All I'm trying to do is deplay a single VS2008 web app to a single EC2 instance. I used to do this with FrontPage, but couldn't for the life of me get that working. I'm now trying FTP, but the docs say I need to allow FTP access using ec2-authorize. Unfortunately I can't see FTP in the management console anywhere.

Comment: I mean, I used to do that with FrontPage with my current web host, not EC2.

Comment: FTP is slightly more complicated compared to the other services. It needs more than just one port to be opened, in order to establish session.

This is old problem with FTP, and it's impact on EC2 is documented  here

http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/thread.jspa?messageID=50327&#50327

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I think I found it finally:

http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=351&categoryID=88

Unfortunately it means I have to install Java. ***sigh*